# Hadoop Hive - Split string

Tags: hive

I am a new hivebe.

**My Query :** In the log file we have a request field like this "GET /img/home/search-user-ico.jpg HTTP/1.1" .There are more than 10,000 records are available.

**Example :**

"GET /img/home/search-user-ico.jpg HTTP/1.1"
"GET /JavaScript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js HTTP/1.1"
"GET /ems/home HTTP/1.1"
"POST /ir HTTP/1.1"
"GET /CSS/jquery/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css HTTP/1.1"
"GET /CSS/jquery/themes/base/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png HTTP/1.1"
"GET /JavaScript/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js HTTP/1.0"

From this field "GET /img/home/search-user-ico.jpg HTTP/1.1"  , i want only this part **/img/home/search-user-ico.jpg** ,i want to split it from GET,POST and HTTP/1.1 so please help me as how to split this using string functions available in wiki.I tried with some of the syntax available in wiki.but i'm helpless now.

i tried with the syntax like,

select regexp_extract(request,'a-zA-Za-zA-Z[a-zA-Z]',2) from logfile limit 10;

select regexp_extract(request,'GET(\s)([a-zA-Z])',2) from logfile limit 10;

select regexp_extract(request,'.*?(\s)(.*?)(\s)(.*?)',2) from logfile limit 10;

select regexp_extract(request,'.*(\s)(.*)(\s)(.*)',2) from logfile limit 10;

Thanks
-Joe

Answer (score 1):

I used [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) and the samples you provided and got just the URLs with this regex `([\S]*) HTTP`
This assumes there will be no literal spaces in the URL, encoded is fine.

Plugging it into a hive query should look something like

```
select regexp_extract(request, ' (\\S*) HTTP', 1) from logfile;
```

(Just to note, there is a space before `(\\S)`. It might be fairly obvious, but just wanted to comment on it in case it was missed)

I have done a little testing in hive and it is working, at least with the tests similar to the samples provided.